# Which is better? Doing basic HTML or loading HTML elements through the use of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been developing a web-based information system that has a User-management functionality on it.

For instance, I'd like the '*Administrator User*' be able to access all the functionalities I've created (adding a student information, editing student info, etc..). And I'd like the "*Client User*' only access retrieval functionalities (retrieve student info, etc...).

Now I think of 2 solutions on how to implement this. It's either doing 2 HTML file for a different user or doing a 1 HTML file that dynamically loads HTML elements in terms of what type of user with the help of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

So here's the scenario, the user will first go through the Log-in page. Then, with the use of [php](/questions/tagged/php), the system will determine whether the user was Admin or Client. After that, the user now will proceed to the page wherein it is dynamically loaded based on his User Type.

Now, I'm stuck on what to choose between these 2 solutions. Any who could enlighten me on which to choose? Thanks in advance! :D

> NOTE: This system is used in Intranet only. It will not be deployed on the internet. The reason I did a web-based system is that of its cross-platform compatibility.

Comment: Another solution would be for the appropriate HTML to be served *by the server itself* (no Javascript, and as separated or integrated as you need)

Comment: Think security, two HTML files doesn't seem like the best option. You're better off using a server-side language like PHP for example to render your items; the problem with JS is that someone can easily inspect your page and find your hidden elements and display them; server-side is the best option not to allow the client to meddle with your code (security-wise). It's also a wiser choice for global deployment on your network;

Comment: Sorry but I can't picture out what you're trying to say. I've edited my post so that you could easily picture out what I'm trying to say. :D

Comment: If you're expecting the client doing the right ting to be responsible for the security of your site you're gonna have a bad time.

Comment: Ohhh. I forgot to mention in my post that it's only used in Intranet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User-management and User`s role management is recommend on server side.User Management at client side having security bleach.

I think its better to keep 1 HTML and do the **role based access control** (RBAC) for the Sections of HTML page.

> RBAC is a model in which roles are created for various job functions, and permissions to perform certain operations are then tied to roles. A user can be assigned one or multiple roles which restricts their system access to the permissions for which they have been authorized.

Some reference:

1. https://github.com/joeflintham/rbac
2. https://github.com/Repox/SimpleUsers
3. https://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/
4. https://github.com/xiidea/ezRbac

Comment: Im using PHP script and a MySQL database. How can I achieve this? Also edited my post to clearly see what I'm trying to point out. Thanks for helping me btw. :D

Comment: Ohh I'm getting your point now. Could you atleast provide some example codes on how to implement this? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really give me some new knowledge. :D